# nginx re-route all data based on port (nginx proxy)

Tags: linux, docker, nginx, networking, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm still new to nginx and I want to accomplish this.

I have two servers (server1 and server2), with an sftp server (bitvise) on server1.
And on server2 I have an nginx docker container running.

I want to configure nginx so when trafic comes to server2 (the one with nginx) on port 22 , it get redirected to server1, where my sftp sever is present.

I have an dns "transfer.test.com" mapped to my server2 public IP (tested).

This is the configuration I have added to nginx conf file.

```
server {
 listen 22;
 server_name transfer.test.com;
 return 301 https://google.com;


 location / {
   set $sftp server1-private-ip:22;
   proxy_pass  $sftp;
  }
}
```

server1-private-ip is the private IP of server1 (the one with sftp).

but till now its not working.
I can connect to sftp using filezile using the private IP of server1 BUT
I can't connect to sftp using filezila using the private IP of server2, means the trafic is not getting redirected.

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to use nginx as a proxy to non-HTTP protocols like SSH or SFTP, you should define your server in a **stream** context rather than **http** one. Typical main configuration file (usually `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`) looks like

```
user              <username>;
worker_processes  <number>;
...

events {
    worker_connections  <number>;
}

http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    ... # other global http directives here
    include       /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

As you can see, configuration files for individual servers (or server groups) are being included within the `http` context. You should add `stream` block to your main configuration file:

```
user              <username>;
worker_processes  <number>;
...

events {
    worker_connections  <number>;
}

http {
    ...
}

stream {
    server {
        listen      22;
        proxy_pass  <server1_private_ip>:22;
    }
}
```

Directives like `server_name` or `location` are meaningless in the `server` blocks defined under the `stream` context. Please note that for using above configuration nginx should be compliled with [`ngx_stream_core_module`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/stream/ngx_stream_core_module.html) and [`ngx_stream_proxy_module`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/stream/ngx_stream_proxy_module.html) modules.

Comment: I added this stream {
    server {
        listen      22;
        set $sftp http://jz-nginx:80;
        proxy_pass  $sftp;
    }
}
to my nginx.conf file, under http{} but still when I curl transfer.test.com i don't get the nginx welcome page, http://jz-nginx:80 where jz-nginx is a local nginx docker container

Comment: and I even tried stream {
    server {
        listen      22;
        proxy_pass  <server1_private_ip>:22;
    }
}
but still when I try to connect to server2_private_ip:22 from filezilla it does not work
Thank you for your help

Comment: What `nginx -t` command says?

Comment: after adding this `stream {
    server {
        listen 22;
        set $sftp <server1-private-ip>:22;
        proxy_pass  $sftp;
    }
}` the nginx -t says :  `nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful`

Comment: nginx configuration file seems to be ok. Sorry, I don't know how to help further. I'm not very familiar with docker networking.