# nginx: [emerg] "stream" directive is not allowed here

Tags: nginx, stream, nginx-config

i'm try to setup load balancer with nginx to keep Client IP at backends node by create file `/etc/nginx/sites-available/test.conf` and symlink for it

```
stream {
    upstream backend_servers {
        server http://server1.com;
        server http://server2.com;
    }
    
    server {
        listen     80;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_pass backend_servers;
    }
}
```

But when i run `nginx -t` to check, this error appear.
can anyone tell me what to do now? Thanks!

Comment: `stream` is a top-level block statement and needs to be in your main Nginx configuration file. The `sites-enabled` directory is intended for configuration fragments that are included into the `http` block. Use `nginx -T` (uppercase `T`) to view the entire configuration across all included files.

Comment: @manhkhoa168 See more detailed explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69221414/7121513).